# error version in custom module magento2 2.0.0-rc?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

i created module in magento2 2.0.00-rc but get error

```
 Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Namespace_Modulename data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
```

i running code **php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade** after get issues same. Any suggestion? thank :].
***code xml module***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="2.0.0" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you check `app/etc/config.php`, is `Namespace_Modulename` enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Check app/code/namespace/modulename/etc/module.xml has

`<module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="2.0.0">`

Note the version 2.0.0

Comment: i edited question

Comment: Have you defined a registration.php file in the modulename root? In previous releases you used a composer.json to register the modules but that has changed.

Comment: yes i created it. In conporser {
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Namespace\\Modulename\\": ""
        }
    }
}